# Allow chrome to select both/either directory or files

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, directory-upload

If I insert `<input type="file" name="files" webkitdirectory>` in a html file, chrome will allow you to select directories, however not files.

If I then remove the webkitdirectory (`<input type="file" name="files">`) then it will only let you choose files.

How do I allow it to choose both/either files and/or directories?

Comment: I'm not familiar with webkitdirectory, but as far as I am aware there isn't a single native dialog at least in Windows for selecting both a directory and/or a file. So I would suggest you implement both tags in your UI and give the user the option to either select a directory or a file or both then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=59818) I filed a while back.